# Nested IF...THEN...ELSE in GW-BASIC

Tags: if-statement, nested, gw-basic

I use following block of code to test some conditions in `gw-basic` program.

```
IF Average >= 80 AND Average <= 100 THEN Grade$ = "A"
IF Average >= 70 AND Average <= 79 THEN Grade$ = "B"
IF Average >= 60 AND Average <= 69 THEN Grade$ = "C"
IF Average >= 50 AND Average <= 59 THEN Grade$ = "D"
IF Average >= 40 AND Average <= 49 THEN Grade$ = "E" ELSE Grade$ = "F"  
PRINT "Average is: ", Average
PRINT "Grade is: ", Grade$
```

It always prints `Grade is: F` whatever is the value of Àverage.

What is the error in this gw-basic program?

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> IF Average >= 40 AND Average <= 49 THEN Grade$ = "E" ELSE Grade$ = "F"
> ```

Because this `IF THEN ELSE` line will always assign a value to *Grade$* (no matter the content of *Average*), all of the previous `IF THEN`'s don't count for much.

The solution however is **very, very simple**. Don't use the `ELSE` clause and give the *Grade$* a default value of "F" to start with. That way, only if all of those conditions evaluate to false, the program will return "Grade is: F".

```
Grade$ = "F"
IF Average >= 80 AND Average <= 100 THEN Grade$ = "A"
IF Average >= 70 AND Average <= 79 THEN Grade$ = "B"
IF Average >= 60 AND Average <= 69 THEN Grade$ = "C"
IF Average >= 50 AND Average <= 59 THEN Grade$ = "D"
IF Average >= 40 AND Average <= 49 THEN Grade$ = "E"
PRINT "Average is: ", Average
PRINT "Grade is: ", Grade$
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose print average line is line number 70, so after each line except the ELSE line write GOTO 70. Try if that works.